# Using C header and implementation files in Xcode iOS project

Tags: ios, c, xcode, header

I'm trying to use a separate C header and implementation file in Xcode iOS/Objective-C project.
I want to use the method I implemented in main.m but I get these errors:

[image]
[Full size here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tytJh.png)

I've included user.h in main.m

Note that Target Membership is selected in user.c for HelloWorld. When I deselect this the errors are gone. But when I try to run the app, I get these errors at compile time:
[image]
[Full size here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIYf9.png)

When I implement the struct and method in main.m it compiles and runs just fine. But I don't get it why I can't use this particular code in a separate file?

*Source Code:*
**user.h**

```
#ifndef HelloWorld_user_h
#define HelloWorld_user_h

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int age;
    char sex;
} User; //sizeof(User) = 16 bytes

void CreateAndDisplay(User *usr, char *name, int age, char sex);

#endif
```

**user.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void CreateAndDisplay(User *usr, char *name, int age, char sex) {
    usr->name = name;
    usr->age = age;
    usr->sex = sex;

    printf("User address -> value:\n");
    printf("Name:\t%u\t->\t%s\n", (uint)usr, *&usr->name);
    printf("Age:\t%u\t->\t%i\n", (uint)&usr->age, *&usr->age);
    printf("Sex:\t%u\t->\t%c\n\n", (uint)&usr->sex, *&usr->sex);

    printf("User has a size of %li bytes in memory", sizeof(*usr));
}
```

**main.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "HelloWorldAppDelegate.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "user.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    User user1;
    CreateAndDisplay(&user1, "John Doe", 24, 'm');

    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([HelloWorldAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Judging just by your [screen snapshot](http://puu.sh/44eMG.png) you might want to try `#include "user.h"` in `user.c`. Looking at the `#include` file list of `user.c`. All that is there is `#include <stdio.h>` so no wonder the compiler has no clue what a `User` is.

Comment: @QuantumHive I moved your screen shots into your post directly. In the future, please actually put the code in your question inside code blocks as it makes your question stand on its own and is easier for others to compile, test, and edit the code on their own. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I will add the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are because there are two types referenced in `user.c` that haven't been declared in headers that it imports: `User` (defined in `user.h`) and `uint` (defined in `<sys/types.h>`). To resolve these errors, inside `user.c` you should add the following includes:

```
#include "user.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to include user.h in user.c, like you include stdio.h.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I didn't know I had to include header files in the C implementation files. One error is gone: it now recognizes the struct. But the other three errors still remain: _"Use of undeclared identifier 'uint': did you mean 'int'?"_ Why am I not able to use **uint**?

Comment: Okay solved the remaining errors. Apparently **uint** is a _typedef_ and not a standard type for C, hence why it doesn't recognize it in the _.c_ file, but does recognize it in the _.m_ file. See [link](http://puu.sh/44hm9.png) for the definition. I've changed **uint** to **unsigned int** in _user.c_ which resolved the errors. **unsigned int** is a standard type for the ANSI C Language.